# Do rep losses from deleted users count against Brunhilde?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2017

Brunhilde is awarded for earning 150 reputation on each of three different sites (other than SO).  I've earned the hat on four sites so far, three initially and the fourth today when I crossed that reputation threshold.  So it appears that the hat isn't a one-time award; once you have it, other sites get added when you meet the requirement there.

As of today I've earned 165 reputation during Winter Bash on Mi Yodeya (or 167 if the +2 for accepting an answer counts).  However, during that time a user was deleted, costing me 20 rep.  It's been more than an hour since the last rep increase, which is longer than it usually takes for hats to show up, and I have not received the hat.

Is this expected behavior?  Is the hat really for a *net increase* of 150, as opposed to *earning* 150?

Comment: yes it is net. If you start a bounty then you have to earn all that again.

Comment: @David oh, I didn't think about bounties.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was at (net) 145 since the beginning of Winter Bash when I asked the question.  In a comment David said it's net and reported that starting a bounty also affects it.  A few minutes ago I received an upvote, putting me over 150, and just received the hat.

So the requirement is *net* reputation gain of 150 in 15 days.  Deleted users, bounties, and presumably your own downvotes count against it.  (I assumed all along that *received* downvotes would.)